# how to find model in ActionCable `subscribed` method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I've seen a lot of tutorials do something like this with the `subscribed` method:

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
 def subscribed
  conversation = Conversation.find(params[:id])
  stream_from "conversation_#{conversation.id}"
 end
end
```

The idea being to allow for multiple conversations between multiple users. But I'm not clear on how that `id` param is sent to the method. If my routes are nested so that the conversation id is in the url, it seems like it *should* work.

```
resources :conversations, only: [:index, :create] do
 resources :messages, only: [:index, :create]
end
```

However, the channel code above gives this error:

```
[ActionCable] [user] Registered connection (Z2lkOi8vZnJhY3Rpb25jbHViL1VzZXIvMQ)
[ActionCable] [user] Could not execute command from ({"command"=>"subscribe", "identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"MessagesChannel\"}"}) [ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Conversation without an ID]: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:431:in `find_with_ids' | /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:69:in `find' | /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/querying.rb:5:in `find' | /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:167:in `find' | /Users/user/code/project/app/channels/messages_channel.rb:3:in `subscribed'
```

How would I pass the conversation id to the `subscribed` method so that my users can have multiple private conversations?

---

*Update 1:* This is my `messages.coffee` file

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create
 channel: "MessagesChannel"
 conversation_id: 1

 connected: ->
  console.log 'Connected'

 disconnected: ->
  console.log 'Disconnected'

 received: (data) ->
  console.log 'Received'
  $('#messages').append(data.message)

 speak: (message, conversation_id) ->
  @perform 'speak', message: message, conversation_id: conversation_id

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
 submit_message()
 scroll_bottom()

submit_message = () ->
 $('#response').on 'keydown', (event) ->
  if event.keyCode is 13
   App.messages.speak(event.target.value)
   event.target.value = ""
   event.preventDefault()

scroll_bottom = () ->
 $('#messages').scrollTop($('#messages')[0].scrollHeight)
```

Comment: Your ActionCable channels are not related to your routes. Your routes respond to normal HTTP requests. Websockets is its own protocol.

Comment: thank you! i only include the routes in my code because other examples i found online use `params` in `subscribed`. the id for that param is present in the url when a user sends a message

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am tackling this,

In my view form:

```
<%= form_for Message.new,remote: true,html: {id: 'new-message',multipart: true} do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :chat_id, value: chat.id,id: 'chat-id' %>
....
```

Notice the id I have given to form and then chat_id field.

Then in my `chat.js`:

```
return App.chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create({
      channel: "ChatChannel",
      chat_id: $('#new-message').find('#chat-id').val()
    }
```

Now I can use this `chat_id` param in my `ChatChannel` like this:

```
def subscribed
  stream_from "chat_#{params['chat_id']}_channel"
end
```

**EDIT:**

In your case:

your MessagesChannel subscribed action should be like this:

```
def subscribed
 stream_from "conversation_#{params[:conversation_id]}"
end
```

Comment: I've updated my question with the code for `messages.coffee` (which would be your `chat.js`). I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Also, would it make more sense to stream from something like `chat_channel_for_user_#{current_user.id}`? I want each user to be subscribed to all the conversations they're participating in.

Comment: I am noticing that you are setting the value of parameter conversation_id to 1 in messages.coffee but you are not reading/using this param in your MessagesChannel, instead you are using params[:id] which is Nil. replace params[:id] with params[:conversation_id].. I have updated my answer..